# Propel.xml gives me an error - Invalid type for path "propel.database.connections.cfs.attributes". Expected array, but got string

Tags: php, propel

I'm opting for an XML file for configuration, but I get the following error when i run `./vendor/bin/propel sql:build`

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException] 
Invalid type for path "propel.database.connections.cfs.attributes". Expected array, but got string
```

Here is my propel.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<config>
    <propel>
        <database>
            <connections>
                <connection id="cfs">
                    <adapter>mysql</adapter>
                    <classname>Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionWrapper</classname>
                    <dsn>mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cfs_development</dsn>
                    <user>cfs_user</user>
                    <password>cfs_pass</password>
                    <attributes></attributes>
                </connection>
            </connections>
        </database>
        <runtime>
            <defaultConnection>cfs</defaultConnection>
            <connection>cfs</connection>
        </runtime>
        <generator>
            <defaultConnection>cfs</defaultConnection>
            <connection>cfs</connection>
        </generator>
    </propel>
</config>
```

.. and my schema.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="cfs" defaultIdMethod="native">
    <table name="projects" phpName="Project" namespace="Cfs\Model">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="title" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
        <column name="user_id" type="integer" required="true"/>
        <foreign-key foreignTable="users" phpName="User">
            <reference local="user_id" foreign="id"/>
        </foreign-key>
    </table>
    <table name="users" phpName="User" namespace="Cfs\Model">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="username" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
        <column name="password" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
        <column name="salt" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
    </table>
</database>
```

I took the details for the propel.xml config file from the official documetation, then it says simply to run the command. But, I get this error? Any suggestions?

I then simply tried to use a PHP file for database config (propel.php) and this time the command run without errors. But, my databases weren't created. I tried to run vendor/bin/propel model:build too to see if it generated my classes, this also run without errors, but I couldn't see where it generated my classes.

Both config files are at the root of my application, which is also where I am running each command from.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like having the configuration file in XML creates interesting issues--

I tried converting the XML to YML with an online converter-- which has given me a different error that I can chase down.

Error using the propel.xml file:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]                                         
Invalid type for path "propel.database.connections.unrestricted.attributes". Expected array, but got string
```

Error using the propel.yml file:

```
[Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]
Unable to parse at line 8 (near "   settings: ").
```

I am going to reread this page:

http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/configuration-file.html

and make any edits I feel will help. I'll update when it works.

Well, it works great.

I used their template and just substituted my database information using the .yml format. I also change my multibyte4utf8 character sets to standard UTF-8 in my database just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You should comment attributes tag in your `config.xml`.

Also your `dbname` in `dsn-config.xml` should be same with name of database tag in your `schema.xml`.

Fix this and try again and that will work great.